# How to integrate payfort payment gateway in swift 2.2?

Tags: swift2, payment-gateway, payfort

I want to **integrate payfort payment gateway** in my app. I have read documentation and download demo of payfort but it is compatible with swift 3.0 and **I want it in swift 2.2.**

I have done so much googling but unfortunately not find any proper solutions.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since the swift syntax has been changed drastically from swift 2 to swift 3, it is a bit much harder to migrate from swift 3 to swift 2.
So, app those are compatible in swift 3 won't be able to be compatible in swift 2.

So, it seems impossible task specially for the newcomers.

What you can do is get the older version of **payfort payment gateway** and you can select the ***version*** of libraries you want to use.

If you can share the link, please do, we could guide you step by step..

Comment: unfortunately payfort library for ios was just release before 2-3 months. So i can't find it for swift 2. I have download and install pod as described in this link (https://github.com/payfort/start-ios-sdk) but in pod files i am getting error.